# Maven "package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, junit5

For context, this is a Java project in Eclipse, using Maven and JUnit5.

So, I have the dependencies listed in my pom:

```
 <dependencies>
    <!--  Junit5 --> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
              <version>1.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/java/</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>14</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

But its still complaining that the API doesn't exist when I try running mvn test. My JUnit5 folder looks like:
[JUnit5 Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAYcP.png)

So its definitely there, and I think the versions are all in order with what I have in the pom. Its not having any issues with the others, only with the API.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I recommend you go with the setup in https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.9.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml. It’s simpler and using the latest versions.

Comment: Your cropped screenshot shows JUnit JARs that are not added via Maven but via Eclipse directly. Does right-clicking the project and choosing _Maven > Update Project..._ fix your issue (there should be then a _Maven Dependencies_ node). Otherwise, show an uncropped screenshot and your full `pom.xml` and your `.classpath` file.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you very much for both of your suggestions; I'll try later and see if I can get it working.